# Are there open data sets with voter turnout and demographic information for local administrative divisions in Mexico?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, elections

I'm looking for data sets with voter turnout data, for both federal and local elections, for small administrative divisions of Mexico, e.g. cities or municipalities. Are such data available? Something similar to the [United States Election Project](http://www.electproject.org/home/voter-turnout/voter-turnout-data), but for Mexico and also for local elections.